# Mask image css so that it only shows a portion of the circle

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve the following round effect on the left hand side image showing on the (using css, I don't want to go the image editor route):

[image]

So far I have tried 2 options:

1. The `::before` route (I only want to show the portion of the photo that sits inside the red square):

```css
html {
  background: yellow;
}

.pre {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.top {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
.top::before {
  content: '';
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik/1600x900");
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -160%;
  z-index: -1;

}
```

```html
<div class="pre"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

However, I don't know how to

- mask the rest of the image
- make the `.pre` div to mask the photo.

2. The second thing I have tried is the `border-top-right-radius` but the effect is not quite the same, not as neat as I would like:

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 50px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #DEDEDE;
  width: 70%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}


.right {
  flex-grow: 3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 20px 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.left {
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  background: url("https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik/1600x900");
  background-size: cover;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Can anyone point me to the right direction?** Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first idea was actually pretty close. You simply forgot to add

```
overflow:hidden;
```

to your `.top` class.

```css
html {
  background: yellow;
}

.pre {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.top {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.top::before {
  content: '';
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik/1600x900");
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -160%;
  z-index: -1;

}
```

```html
<div class="pre"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```